ffmpeg: Convert video file to separate WebP images
I want to covert the input video file to a set of WebP images: one for each frame.
I'm trying to use the common video-to-images pattern:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f image2 frame%04d.webp

But all I get is a single animated file frame0001.webp
Is there any param to force ffmpeg to generate a separate file for each frame?

I think this does what you want:
ffmpeg -i YOURINPUT -codec libwebp frame-%03d.webp


You can get a list of all coders that relate to WEBP (along with the key to the symbols at the top) like this:
ffmpeg -v warning -codecs | grep -Ei "=|webp"

 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ..D... = Data codec
 ..T... = Attachment codec
 ...I.. = Intra frame-only codec
 ....L. = Lossy compression
 .....S = Lossless compression

 DEVILS webp                 WebP (encoders: libwebp_anim libwebp)

That tells you that there are two encoders, namely libwebp_anim and libwebp, so that's how I decided to use libwebp because it doesn't do animation, unlike libwebp_anim.
Once you know the encoder you want to use, you can find the options it supports like this:
ffmpeg -v warning -h encoder=libwebp  
   
Encoder libwebp [libwebp WebP image]:
    General capabilities: dr1 
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported pixel formats: bgra yuv420p yuva420p
libwebp encoder AVOptions:
  -lossless          <int>        E..V....... Use lossless mode (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
  -preset            <int>        E..V....... Configuration preset (from -1 to 5) (default none)
     none            -1           E..V....... do not use a preset
     default         0            E..V....... default preset
     picture         1            E..V....... digital picture, like portrait, inner shot
     photo           2            E..V....... outdoor photograph, with natural lighting
     drawing         3            E..V....... hand or line drawing, with high-contrast details
     icon            4            E..V....... small-sized colorful images
     text            5            E..V....... text-like
  -cr_threshold      <int>        E..V....... Conditional replenishment threshold (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
  -cr_size           <int>        E..V....... Conditional replenishment block size (from 0 to 256) (default 16)
  -quality           <float>      E..V....... Quality (from 0 to 100) (default 75)


Thank you! This helps. I've found that ffmpeg uses libwebp_anim codec by default.

You could let ffmpeg create a png file for each frame and then convert the png files to webp afterwards.
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "fps=1" frame%04d.png

